# joy_node using ~3gb of RAM

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't been able to find any other reports of this issue, but when running joy_node on my robot, it appears to have a memory leak, jumping in memory use every few seconds, until it consumes all of the available system memory. There was a similar issue reported here: [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/199753/ros-serviceclient-memory-leak/), but it appears to have been fixed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298427/joy_node-using-%7E3gb-of-ram/) by [NicholasGarcia](https://answers.ros.org/users/36610/nicholasgarcia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whoops, set the rosconsole level to DEBUG, mistakenly attributed to joy_node

---

Originally posted by [NicholasGarcia](https://answers.ros.org/users/36610/nicholasgarcia/) with karma: 16 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0